# Redis unlink hash - is the hash treated as a whole or not?

Tags: c, algorithm, redis, hash

e.g:
In redis, the hash is:

```
ha -> {
  k1 -> v1
  k2 -> v2
  k3 -> v3
}
```

When `unlink ha`, how would redis actually delete it?
*(assume values of the 3 sub keys are large enough to make redis decide to remove them in a separate thread).*

**The possible ways I can image:**

- A. Remove single key `ha`, then later remove the whole value (with 3 sub keys) as a whole, in another thread.
- B. Remove key `ha`, and sub keys `k1`, `k2`, `k3`. Then later remove the 3 values of the sub keys?

So which is the case, or there are more ways?

---

### Relevant redis source code

https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/3ca451c46fed894bf49e7561fa0282d2583f1c06/src/dict.c#L553

According to the code above, seems it's more like case B.
That make sense, since hashtable store reference to value, not in a single memory block, thus need to free the values 1 by 1, right ?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `unlink` to remove a key (hash or any other structure), Redis deletes it logically by removing it (key, sub key, and value) from the DB, and putting it into a to-be-deleted list. There will be a background job that deletes these lazily removed items from another thread. When Redis does the real delete job, it delete everything about the key (key, sub key, and value).